# Azure B2C Twitter ID provider not working

Tags: azure, twitter, azure-ad-b2c

I'm setting up for our netwerk of entrepreneurs an Azure B2C with several ID providers (Facebook, Github, Microsoft, Google, LinkedIn and Twitter). All except Twitter are working (getting back tokens). I have followed all steps as described by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-twitter), also deleted and created again Twitter App as well as ID provider, however nothing seems to help. And because the error message is to vague I'm not able to troubleshoot this issue. I've seen that other users, with a previous working Twitter ID, are having issues after an update, however in my case, not even getting up-n-running for the first time. 
Any advise on how to troubleshoot it ? Thanks ! 
[Twitter ID provider error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWi72.png)

Comment: We see you are getting a HTTP 403 (Forbiddon) from Twitter after when we try to redeem the authorization code for an access token at `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token`. Make sure you have the correct client_secret setup in B2C that is generated from the Twitter Dev Portal Application Registration. Also next time paste the error in text so we don't have to type out GUIDs.

Comment: Thanks @JasSuri for the update. I have though of that as well, so I've made sure that a copy-paste action takes place, regenerated 3x times the consumers API keys. I've even tested with Acces tokens and Secrets. Still the same issue. I know that with some ID providers a status "online" or similar is required, not sure if this is the same case for Twitter ? I've even deleted the App on Twitter and created a new one. Still the same results. PS. l'll follow up your suggestion next time, thx.

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved ! The problem was not on the Customer API Keys, but in the Call-back URL. Very important to pay attention to every letter within. Every User-flow has its own Id (name) and try to keep it short, otherwise 1 letter can get away. Should be very easy to guess, but sometime this slips my eyes..

Comment: In the call back URL, make sure to use all lowercase letters when entering your tenant name and user flow ID even if they are defined with uppercase letters in Azure AD B2C